# Interesting geometry problem : need a hint

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

Consider a triangle $ABC$, where $\angle A = 60°$.
Let $O$ be the inscribed circle of triangle $ABC$,
as shown in the figure. Let $D, \,E$ and $F$ be
the points at which circle is tangent to the sides $AB,\,BC$ and $CA$. And let $G$ be the point of intersection of the line segment $AE$ and the circle $O$. Set $x = AD$.

If $\triangle ADF$ be the area of the triangle $ADF$. Then $$\frac{\triangle ADF}{AG.AE}=$$

[image]

---

**My attempt :** I have found the radius of the $A$-excircle of $ADF$ or $ABC$'s incentre and $ADF$'s area. But I don't know how how to relate it to $AG.AE$.

Need a hint.

Comment: What does the "A" in the box mean?

Comment: It's an order for the answer script. No need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\triangle AGD\sim \triangle ADE$.

$$\frac{AG}{AD}=\frac{AD}{AE}$$

Comment: This is actually the Power of a point Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point

Answer (score 1):

Let $[ADF]$ denote the area of triangle $ADF.\;\,$Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{[ADF]}{AG\cdot AE}&=
\frac{{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(AD)(AF)\sin{60^\circ}}{AG\cdot AE}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(AD)^2\sin{60^\circ}}{AG\cdot AE}
&&\text{[equal tangent lengths from a point]}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}(AD)^2\sin{60^\circ}}{(AD)^2}
&&\text{[power-of-a-point]}\\[6pt]
&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\sin{60^\circ}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}